# How do i add multiple events to a binding in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, bind

I want to bind a widget to a single function so when its clicked and the "r" key is being pressed at the same time it gets called.

i have tryed `<Button-1-R>` and got the error "_tkinter.TclError: extra characters after detail in binding"

`widged.bind("<Button-1>",function)`

Comment: I do not believe `.bind()` works on buttons this way. Bind works on other widgets but I believe because buttons have the `command` section binding to a button in this way does not work.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks Bryan. I was having a hard time finding any documentation and I was guessing because tkinter already has a command argument that `.bind()` was not needed for button widgets.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: no, `bind` works universally for all widgets. Internally, tkinter uses `bind` to implement the `command` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to bind combinations, you can do so with a single bind by concatenating the events. You can optionally add whitespace between each event.

For example, to bind a click followed by pressing the "r" key you can do it like so:

```
widget.bind("<ButtonPress-1> <r>", function)
```

If you want the reverse -- the letter "r" followed by a click, just reverse them. However, you may have difficulties depending on your system since some systems have an autorepeat for keys.

```
widget.bind("<r><ButtonPress-1>", function).
```

It's important to know that tkinter processes events literally. For example, if you click the button and then press "r", the binding will fire. If you press "r" again the binding won't fire since it isn't immediately preceeded by a click.

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but the other solution is to set a flag in the handler for one event (either the click or the key), and check for the flag in the other.

For example:

```
def set_flag(value):
    global flag
    flag = True

def function(event):
    if flag:
        ... process the event here ...

widget.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: set_flag(True))
widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: set_flag(False))
widget.bind("<r>", function)
```

Comment: I did figure this part out with the research I did however because it does not work on a button maybe adding a frame around the button and binding to the frame would work instead? I think that would do the trick here.

Comment: NVM Bryan I need to read the OPs question more closely. I thought they wanted to use this on a button.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: it would work on a button, too. However, a button typically doesn't have focus so it might not ever see the keyboard event .

Answer (score 1):

You can capture 3 events: `<Button-1>`, `<r>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>`. Fire your function only when both button 1 and r is triggered.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.insert(0,"Left click and press R")
entry.pack()

class Bindings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.but_1 = False
        entry.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouse_clicked)
        entry.bind("<r>", self.r_clicked)
        entry.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.mouse_release)

    def mouse_release(self,event):
        self.but_1 = False

    def mouse_clicked(self,event):
        self.but_1 = True
        print ("Mouse button 1 clicked")

    def r_clicked(self,event):
        if self.but_1:
            print ("Both keys clicked")
            self.but_1 = False
        else:
            print ("Key R pressed")

Bindings()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is being used in an entry field and not on a Button. The OP is specifically looking for the functionality with a button.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I thought he said a widget but didn't specify a button?  He did mention button but that's the binding for mouse button 1.

Comment: Oh. You are correct. For some reason I miss read the OPs question and believed it was needed for a button...

Comment: Well, at least Bryan showed a proper way to do it :)

Comment: I was doing the same thing but I was trying to make it work with a button this entire time lol. That's what I get for not reading fully the question.